# data type for timestamp in Tableau to read quickly?

Tags: database, visualization, tableau-api, vertica, impala

We want to query big dataset into Tableau from Backend datastore (Example Vertica). timestamp is in TIMESTAMP. Because we going to create filter on timestamp field in Tableau dashboard, which will restrict the query run time.

right now datatype for timestamp field is TIMESTAMP and when Tableau query that time it uses CAST which make query to run slow.

So anyone know best way to workaround this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, you're presenting the timestamp in Tableau as a Unix timestamp?

Comment: Not sure, I am connecting to table stored into database & tableau recognises it as Date & Time format.

Comment: Can you talk to someone who can find out?

Comment: I have corrected my question, sorry for confusion